# can we create an Android studio project Manually?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I want to create Android studio project Manually rather than AndroidStudio,
I have created the folder structure and file same as generated by Android Studio but when i build it through command 
**./gradlew assembleDebug**

Its give output
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'assembleDebug' not found in root project 'NewApplication'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with                                              --info                                                                           or                                                                             --debug                                                                          option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.054 secs

Please help
Thanks in Advance

Comment: what would be the point of doing this?

Comment: I need to generate apk file through command but when i create project manually(Not by Android Studio) i cant generate Apk file.

Comment: You appear to be missing something in your `build.gradle` files. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your project. Ideally, this includes all of your Gradle build files.

Comment: I don't think that anything is missing.i have copied the content of Android studio generated projects to my manually files.

Comment: Why not create the project with Android Studio and build it with the command line?

Comment: i know that works.i have to use new way

Comment: Check all fileName spell correctly ,if u created it manually.

Comment: There are lots of reason for this. Please stop telling everyone you don't need this. Full automatisation is an absolute 100% requirement in every good software company. And this includes generating  projects (for testing, instrumentation or whatever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, we can create an Android studio project manually. But you need to write files same as generated by Android Studio (For that you can refer files of Android Studio's generated code).
Most of the files are static i.e. common for all projects.

The Structure of Android Studio Project contains the following files that are least required.

module-name

```
       --libs
       --src
       --main
             --java(contains your packages)
             --res(contains layout,drawables,menu,values etc directories)
             --AndroidManifest.xml
             --build.gradle(Module)
```

*Gradle directory

```
        --wrapper subdirectory
                --gradle-wrapper.jar
                --gradle-wrapper.properties
```

*build.gradle(Project)

*gradlew (Required on Linux)

*gradlew.bat(Required on Windows)

*local.properties(shows  Location of the SDK)

*settings.gradle(It has entry of your modules)

The files which are common for all projects are

setting.gradle,
local.properties,
gradlew.bat,
gradlew,
build.gradle,
gradle-wrapper.jar,
gradle-wrapper.properties

After creating this files and structrte you can also generate build of your project i.e.**apk** by using the following command

go to your project direcory and run Following commands

chmod +x gradlew

./gradlew assembleDebug

If you have done no error then your apk will be generated in

Module-name/build/outputs/apk
**app-debug.apk**

You can intall your apk and enjoy.